# Devise 3.1 Account Confirmed When Email Link Has not Been Used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

Been looking around for a solution and couldn't find any. I am trying to skip sending of the confirmation email and send it after a user account's password has been set. However, after the password is set the confirmed_at is also set, so it gets confirmed before the email confirmation link is used. Below is my code. Thanks in advance

I am skipping confirmation with this (user.rb)

```
before_save :skip_confirmation

def skip_confirmation
 self.skip_confirmation!
end
```

Then when the user has set a password (user_controller.rb)

```
# Updating user password fields
               ....    
@user.send_confirmation_instructions if password_set
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is because `skip_confirmation!` actually marks the account as confirmed (sets the `confirmed_at` column).  To just skip sending the confirmation email, use `skip_confirmation_notification!` instead.  It looks like you're using some customised code (user_controller.rb), as with the normal devise registration process the confirmation email wouldn't be sent until a user had been created, including a password.